# How to insert data into many database tables received from a single form? Django/MySql

Tags: mysql, django-models, django-forms

I'm a bit stuck on Django code to insert data into multiple MySQL tables. I am unable to get the data into many tables within a single action. I have 3 tables in my database.

Table encours:
[image: Table encours],

Table  OF:
[image: Table OF],

Table Poste:
[image: Table Poste]

I want when the user logs in and enters the product number into The form which is showed below, that information be saved in three tables at the same time for the given attribute.

[image: The form]

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do You need to save one value in three tables with multi column? Where is the other value provided?

Comment: I want to save the time of saving one value ( Numero_OF mentioned in the table OF) in three tables with multi-column. For example, I have to enter the number of product  214544458745 and this information will save in the table OF and more precisely in the column Numero_OF. At the same time, I have to recover the time of entering this information in two tables encours ( in the attribute date_E_encours )and poste ( in the attribute date_S_Poste ).

Comment: You can use Triggers in mysql to do that.